# Why does calling a function after a for loop terminates cause the index variable to be the same?

Tags: javascript

Got asked this at a "Junior" Web Developer interview. They asked what is the output of

```
var funcs = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
{
    funcs.push(function ( ) { console.log("i = " + i); });    
}
funcs.forEach(function ( el ) { el(); });
```

is and they asked me to explain why. Well, I screwed up. Later I went on JSFiddle and found out that the output is

```
i = 5 
i = 5
i = 5
i = 5
i = 5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wen3us7y/

and I figured out that it has to do with the `for` loop causing a closure. But still, I don't understand how the `i` on the right side of the expression `"i = " + i` is updated as `i` increments. I would understand if it were `console.log(i)` but doesn't the fact that `i` is in a mathematical expression make that expression an r-value???? I've never heard of a programming language where you can do something like

```
i = 5;
y = 2 + i;
++i;
// now y is 8
```

This is chaos. Society cannot function like this.

Comment: Also, you may read this: http://conceptf1.blogspot.com/2013/11/javascript-closures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a closure, and the variables are scoped on function level, no block level.

So after your for loop, the `i` is still defined, and its value is 5, because it the last value before exiting the loop.

The console log and the string concatenation is executed in the `forEach`, so there `i` already has its value, 5

If you want to have a variable in block level, you should use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), but keep in mind it is a feature of javascript6

```
for ( let i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
```

In that case, your `i` in the `console.log` will be undefined, since `i` is no longer accesible